# version control for code and output models

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameter-tuning, version-control

I have a question about version control for both code and the models it generates. We are developing ML models that often involve hyperparameters and so we might do many runs with different hyperparameter settings. We currently store the output models in cloud buckets, but we keep the code in Github or BitBucket.
This seems to invite things to get out of synch.
I guess we could store both code and output models in the same place, but for code Github seems best but not so good for data like models. Any suggestions on how others manage this?

Comment: Have you looked at [mlflow](https://mlflow.org/) yet? It's an open source platform built around the machine learning lifecycle and allows you to easily version and save your models

Comment: Had not looked at mlflow, but I will.  Thanks greatly.